# How would I find a parametric solution for the following Diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$a^2bc(b-c)(b+c) + d^2ef(e-f)(e+f) = g^2hi(h-i)(h+i)$

Is this even possible given our current understanding of number theory? If so, which areas of number theory would help me in finding a parametric form(s) for this Diophantine equation?

Edit: I should mention that I'm also interested in finding parametric solutions to the simpler equation:

$bc(b-c)(b+c) + ef(e-f)(e+f) = hi(h-i)(h+i)$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "OP" second part of question.

Actually the equation represent's in

disguise three triangles with equal areas.

$$2ab(a^2-b^2)/2=2cd(c^2-d^2)/2=2ef(e^2-f^2)/2$$

Solution is:

$(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(169,15,176,169,169,161)$

Reference see:

[OEIS A055193](https://oeis.org/A055193)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic here. Are you describing a right triangle with height $a^2 - b^2$ and base $2ab$? Could you give me a quick explanation for why this connection exists?

Answer (score 0):

"OP" needed a parametric solution to second part of question.

ab(a^2-b^2)=cd(c^2-d^2)=ef(e^2-f^2)

a=c=f=m^2+mn+n^2

b=m^2-n^2

d=n(2m+n)

e=m(m+2n)

for (m,n)=(3,2) we have,

(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(19,5,19,16,22,19)

Comment: Thank you! It's not too difficult to find solutions where some of the variables share a common value. I'm curious to find solutions and perhaps parametric forms when b != c != e != f =! h != i

Comment: In other words, where none of the variables equal each other

Comment: One more point: I believe you read my equation as $ab(a^2-b^2)=cd(c^2-d^2)=ef(e^2-f^2) $when I in fact wrote $ab(a^2-b^2) + cd(c^2-d^2)=ef(e^2-f^2)$ with a plus sign

Answer (score 0):

Equation,  $bc(b-c)(b+c) + ef(e-f)(e+f) = hi(h-i)(h+i)$

@antoniomathgini in the 2nd part of his

question requested (parametric solution) to above equation.

Solution is given below:

$b=(4w+3)(2w+3)$

$c=6w$

$e=2w(4w+3)$

$f=3(2w+3)$

$h=(8w^2+12w+9)$

$(i)=3(4w+3)$

For, $w=2$, we get:

$(b,c,e,f,h,i)=(77,12,44,21,65,33)$